# Confusing about network bits in classless and classful addressing

Tags: routing, subnet, ip-address

**In class ful addressing:**
The network bits must match:
For class A first octect
For class B first two octects
For Class C first three Octects

What about Classless addressing? 
Network ids derived from subnetmask. Is it mandatory to match first three octects in 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2 ipaddress?

In classless how systems feels they are on same network? On what criteria they derive network address?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

First:  Classful addressing is obsolete and is no  longer used.  It was obsolete (I'm guessing) since before you were born.  A pox on schools that keep teaching it.

Second: Dividing an IP address into  octets is just for the convenience of human readers.  To the computer, it is just a 32-bit address.  There is no meaning to the octets other than it makes it easier for humans to read big binary numbers.

Third:  The subnet mask defines which bits are the network ID and which are the host ID.  The 1's bits indicate the network portion of the address.

Comment: "_There is no meaning to the octets other than it makes it easier for humans to read big binary numbers._" Based on my personal experience, don't ever say that on [sf] or other SE sites; you will be shouted down. :) Some people just don't get it.

Comment: A pox on them too ;-p